# How to go to another page clicking on Table Row from react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-table

I am not being able to go to another page when I click on table row.

I am already using the getTdProps function to get properties from the table row when I click at a specific row - everything it is working for that.
The problem is that I don't know how to go to another screen using 'react-router' when I get the "onClick" event. 
I also don't want to use the "link" function from "react-router", since this function highlight in blue the words from the table.

````
```export default class Lista2 extends Component{
    constructor(){        
        super();
        this.state = {
            list: []
        }                
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getList();       
    }

    getList(){
        axios.put(proxyurl + url, {
            "owner": 2
        }).then(res => {      
            this.setState({ list: res.data})
       })
   }

   render(){ 
        const columnsTable = [
                {
                    Header: "ID",
                    accessor: "id",
                    width: 120,
                },
                {
                    Header: "Setor",
                    accessor: "setor"
                },
                {
                    Header: "Máquina",
                    accessor: "maquina"
                },
                {
                    Header: "Sensor",
                    accessor: "sensor"
                }]

        let tableStyle = {
            //backgroundColor: "#FCFD96",
            marginRight: "auto",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginBottom: "20px",
            fontSize: "14px",
            textAlign: "center",
        }

        return( 
            <Main {...headerProps}>
                <div>                              
                    <ReactTable
                        data= {this.state.list}
                        columns={columnsTable}
                        showPaginationBottom= {true}
                        className= "-striped -highlight"
                        style={tableStyle}
                        noDataText = {"Please Wait"}                        
                        getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
                            return {
                              onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                                console.log('A Td Element was clicked!')
                                console.log('it produced this event:', e)
                                console.log('It was in this column:', column)
                                console.log('It was in this row:', rowInfo)
                                console.log('It was in this table instance:', instance)
                              }
                            }
                          }}

                    />    
                </div>              
            </Main>
        )        
    }
} ```
````

I would like to know how can I go to another screen, clicking on the entire row from the table?
Should I call another function?
What feature from react-router should I use?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a codepen example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history.push` from `react-router`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Lista2 extends Component {
  ....
  onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
    this.props.history.push('some-page')
    console.log('A Td Element was clicked!')
    console.log('it produced this event:', e)
    console.log('It was in this column:', column)
    console.log('It was in this row:', rowInfo)
    console.log('It was in this table instance:', instance)
  }
}

export default withRouter(Lista2)
```

Comment: it worked!
can I pass props using withRouter? How can I do that?

Comment: No. `withRouter` help you access `history` object. And you can go to another page with `history,push`

Answer (score 0):

In your getTdProps function, you can use this to be redirected to another route of your app:

```js
window.location("YOUR_ROUTE");
```

Example:

```js
getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
  return {
    onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
      window.location("/#/home")
    }
  }
}}
```

This will redirect to `www.reactApp.com/#/home`, if the route `/home` in your router leads to a new page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can I pass props to another page using window.location? How can I do that?

Comment: No you actually can't, because it completely changes the page you're on, so it will "lose" the props/state that you had on your current page. However, what you could do is add a variable in your route as a quick fix. Not the prettiest thing though, but helps passing some info you need to the new page.

Comment: I am getting the following error --> "Lista2.jsx:134 Uncaught TypeError: window.location is not a function"
Do I have to declare the "window.location" before?

Comment: No you don't, `window` is normally native to javascript and supported by all browsers, check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) for more info on window.location. It's weird that it returns an error though, you're sure to have written it properly ? :/

Comment: I tried again, but it didn't work.
Anyway, I need to pass props to another page by clicking on the row. I am trying to use "Link" bellow the getTdprops function but it not working. 
Do you know if I can use "Link" from react-router in that location of the code?